# ¿Cómo obtener el siguiente resultado de una consulta a partir de un parámetro?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Os pongo en antecedentes:

Tengo una `base de datos` con una tabla llamada `entradas`, a cada entrada que hago en el blog, se le crean sus correspondientes campos, entre ellos el `id` (mediante autoincrement  y empezando en 1).

En el `html`, cargo una entrada (Ya sea la ultima entrada o X entrada, o la primera, por poner un ejemplo). Justo debajo del texto de la entrada, tengo dos : `Siguiente entrada y entrada anterior`.

Ahora viene lo importante del asunto. ¿Cómo determino cuál es la siguiente y anterior entrada? Imaginaos que tengo cuatro entradas (ID 1, 2, 3, 4) Y me da por borrar la segunda, entonces queda: ID: 1, 3, 4.

¿Cómo sé ahora, que mi siguiente entrada (Empezando por la primera ID:1) es la que tiene ID 3? Me imagino que tendría que pasar un parámetro a esa funcion ($id) y a partir de ese parámetro, calcular el siguiente registro en la tabla de la base de datos, pero no sé cómo.

Espero haberme explicado bien. El caso es que lo estoy haciendo mediante codeigniter, y no sé cómo aplicarlo ni hacerlo.

Edito con la respuesta proporcionada por [Mauricio Villa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/51075). He cambiado algunas cosas, si alguien logra mejorar su eficiencia y código, sea bienvenido:

```
public function nextEntrada($id){

    [mas lineas de códigos]

    $condicion = false;
    $cont = 0;

        while($condicion == false || $cont < $this->mi_modelo->numeroDeEntradas()){
            $entradaDatos = array ( "entrada" => $this->mi_modelo->obtenerEntrada($id)); 
            $num = $this->mi_modelo->numDeEntradasAfectadas($id); 

            if($num > 0){ 
                $condicion = true;
            }
            else{ 
                $id--;
            }

            $cont++;
        }   

     [mas lineas de codigo]
}
```

Edito por última vez, al final he usado la respuesta de [Irving Zamora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/62347) que me ha parecido más eficiente.

> Controlador:

```
public function nextEntrada($id){

    [mas lineas de códigos]

            $resultado = $this->mi_modelo->siguiente_entrada_model($id); 

     [mas lineas de codigo]
}
```

> Modelo:

```
public function siguiente_entrada_model($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('TABLA');
        $this->db->where("(id>'{$id}'");
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit('1');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $q->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscar de uno por uno hasta encontrar la "siguiente entrada" es ineficiente.
Intenta realizar la siguiente consulta en tu BD por su puesto usando tu notación en CodeIgniter.

```
SELECT 'CAMPOS' FROM 'TABLE' WHERE ID > '$ID' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Lo que el query hace es:
Selecciona los campos que deseas de la tabla que deseas,
donde el id sea mayor al que provees, y obtienes solo 1 ("La siguiente entrada")

Para "la anterior entrada" solo cambia ">" por "<"

Espero sea de tu ayuda

```
public function nextEntrada($id){

    [mas lineas de códigos]

            $resultado = $this->mi_modelo->siguiente_entrada_model($id); 

     [mas lineas de codigo]
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function siguiente_entrada_model($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('TABLA');
        $this->db->where("id>'{$id}'");
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit('1');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $q->result();
    }
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1' at line 4

SELECT * FROM `mis_posts` WHERE (`id` > '20' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: He usado tu código (Pero cambiando el nombre de la tabla, obviamente y sustituyendo la variable del return "$q" por "$query" y en vez de "->result()" por "->row". Igualmente, el problema creo que viene del where.

Comment: Solucionado, había metido un "(" donde no debía". Me parece mucho mas eficiente tu forma de hacerlo, gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: Tienes razón, por error puse "(" donde no debía, ya corregí la respuesta, que bueno que te funciono amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que `siguiente entrada` y `entrada anterior` son enlaces, si es así podrías enviarles el `id` de la entrada actual +1 y -1 para `siguiente entrada` y `entrada anterior` respectivamente, lo que significa que le estarías enviando a tu controlador el `id` para realizar la consulta, si el resultado de la consulta es mayor a cero lo puedes retornar a la vista de lo contrario vuelve a realizar la consulta sumandole uno hasta encontrar un valor para `siguiente entrada` y para el caso de `anterior entrada` crea otro controlador y haz lo mismo pero en vez de sumarle 1 a el `id` restale 1, ya es cuestión de que hagas tu lógica en  los controladores. un ejemplo:

`Controller:`

```
public function siguiente_entrada($id)
    {
        $condicion = false;
        while(condicion == false){
            $datos['arrDatos'] = $this->tu_modelo->consult_siguiente_entrada($id);
            if($datos->num_rows > 0){
                $condicion = true;
            }else{
                $id++
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('tu_vista', $datos);
    }
```

`Model:`

```
public function siguiente_entrada_model($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('campos_de_tu_tabla');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('entradas');
        return $q->result();
    }
```

espero te sirva, cualquier cosa solo comenta.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, tu idea me ha servido perfectamente, pero he modificado un poco el código.